# Abbreviate certain strings (dplyr syntax)

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I am working in R with Eurostat data that has among its variables `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, which in turn often takes on values like `"Euro Area - 12 countries  (2001-2006)"` or `"European Union - 27 countries (from 2020)"`. Now, I would like to abbreviate all the values in `Geopolitical entity (reporting)` that start with "Euro" such that I am only left with values like EA12 or EU27, i.e. keep the first letter of the first two words and then the number of countries. I know I need to use `mutate` and `case_when` and `gsub` or `sub`, but I was never good in regular expressions. For context:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(eurostat) 
df <- get_eurostat("spr_exp_pens",type = "label")
colnames(df)[1:5] <- label_eurostat_vars(df)
```

Further, I know I need to continue on:

```
df %>% mutate(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)` = 
       case_when( ...
```

Can anyone help me out here?

---

EDIT: I realized that `Geopolitical entity (reporting)` assumes also the values `Germany (until 1990 former territory of the FRG)` and `European Economic Area (EEA18-1995, EEA28-2004, EEA30-2007, EEA31-2013, EEA30-2020)` and would like to shorten those too (to `Germany` and `EEA`).

And I made some progress:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)` =
           case_when(
             grepl("Germany", `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Germany",
             startsWith(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "Euro") ~
               sub("^([A-Za-z])[A-Za-z]*\\s([A-Za-z])[A-Za-z]*\\s-\\s(\\d+).*", "\\U\\1\\U\\2\\3", `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, perl = TRUE),
             startsWith(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "European Economic Area") ~ "EEA",
             TRUE ~ `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`))
```

However, two values are still there:

- `European Economic Area (EEA18-1995, EEA28-2004, EEA30-2007, EEA31-2013, EEA30-2020)`
- `Euro area – 20 countries (from 2023)`

Can someone explain why and how to fix these last issues?

Comment: Maybe [this demo](https://tio.run/##TY7BagJBEETv8xXFnLrjbtgdxUBIEA9@gre@qBllIJmRnl0IJH772gqCl6YOr@q1TlP9TnXAR4sDOcBvRi1Ya9yhRR9wKGMeNMUKUOi6vrWzZN880HPcZWxzKtn48PbE01HLD0IXOvaOndN4ir/m8bRhK9Lq/dblFSzRms34T1u@LbFNkcjXjF9fvHPHoqCKlHF/ld2fydUMnzjVcU/34QZepBcJInORhW9QGcadNeXBkMruMk1X) will help. It uses [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (also see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QbXLCA/1)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for adding your own attempts to solve the problem - it makes it a lot easier to help - here is a potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
# install.packages("eurostat")
library(eurostat)
df <- get_eurostat("spr_exp_pens",type = "label")
colnames(df)[1:5] <- label_eurostat_vars(df)

df %>%
  mutate(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)` = case_when(
    str_detect(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "Euro area") ~ paste0(
      "EA", str_extract(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "\\d+")
      ),
    str_detect(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "European Union") ~ paste0(
      "EU", str_extract(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "\\d+")
    ),
    str_detect(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "Germany") ~ "Germany",
    str_detect(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "European Economic Area") ~ "EEA",
    TRUE ~ `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`)
  ) %>%
  select(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  print(n = 50)
#> # A tibble: 45 × 1
#>    `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`
#>    <chr>                            
#>  1 Austria                          
#>  2 Ireland                          
#>  3 Lithuania                        
#>  4 Latvia                           
#>  5 Malta                            
#>  6 Albania                          
#>  7 Belgium                          
#>  8 Bulgaria                         
#>  9 Switzerland                      
#> 10 Cyprus                           
#> 11 Czechia                          
#> 12 Germany                          
#> 13 Denmark                          
#> 14 EA12                             
#> 15 EA19                             
#> 16 EA20                             
#> 17 Estonia                          
#> 18 Greece                           
#> 19 Spain                            
#> 20 EU27                             
#> 21 Finland                          
#> 22 France                           
#> 23 Croatia                          
#> 24 Hungary                          
#> 25 Iceland                          
#> 26 Italy                            
#> 27 Luxembourg                       
#> 28 Montenegro                       
#> 29 Netherlands                      
#> 30 Norway                           
#> 31 Poland                           
#> 32 Portugal                         
#> 33 Romania                          
#> 34 Serbia                           
#> 35 Sweden                           
#> 36 Slovenia                         
#> 37 Slovakia                         
#> 38 Türkiye                          
#> 39 Bosnia and Herzegovina           
#> 40 EA18                             
#> 41 EU15                             
#> 42 EU28                             
#> 43 United Kingdom                   
#> 44 EEA                              
#> 45 North Macedonia
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If this list looks correct, remove the `select()` and `distinct()` to get your solution:

```r
df_2 <- df %>%
  mutate(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)` = case_when(
    str_detect(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "Euro area") ~ paste0(
      "EA", str_extract(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "\\d+")
      ),
    str_detect(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "European Union") ~ paste0(
      "EU", str_extract(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "\\d+")
    ),
    str_detect(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "Germany") ~ "Germany",
    str_detect(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`, "European Economic Area") ~ "EEA",
    TRUE ~ `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`)
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

To demonstrate the answer I have selected only the relevant column and rows and saved the output in new column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(grepl('^Euro', `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`)) %>%
  select(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)`) %>%
  mutate(res = toupper(sub('E[a-z]+\\s(.)[a-z]+\\s[-–]\\s(\\d+).*', 'E\\1\\2', 
                       `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`)))

#  `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`          res  
#   <chr>                                     <chr>
# 1 Euro area - 12 countries (2001-2006)      EA12 
# 2 Euro area - 19 countries  (2015-2022)     EA19 
# 3 Euro area – 20 countries (from 2023)      EA20 
# 4 European Union - 27 countries (from 2020) EU27 
# 5 Euro area - 12 countries (2001-2006)      EA12 
# 6 Euro area - 18 countries (2014)           EA18 
# 7 Euro area - 19 countries  (2015-2022)     EA19 
# 8 Euro area – 20 countries (from 2023)      EA20 
# 9 European Union - 27 countries (from 2020) EU27 
#10 Euro area - 12 countries (2001-2006)      EA12 
# ℹ 17,126 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

This uses capturing group where the first capturing group is the first letter after `E... -`  and the second one is number that comes after `-–`.

In your actual data there is other data as well, we can use `ifelse` with `grepl` to change only relevant values.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(`Geopolitical entity (reporting)` = ifelse(grepl('^Euro', 
         `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`), 
         toupper(sub('E[a-z]+\\s(.)[a-z]+\\s[-–]\\s(\\d+).*', 'E\\1\\2', 
        `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`)), `Geopolitical entity (reporting)`))
```